# Django, adding a readonly field (from instance method) to a modelform.

Tags: django, modelform

In Django's admin, you can add instance method calls to an edit page via the readonly option.

Can I do something similar with a ModelForm, and display the results of an instance method call? Preferably making it part of the forms visible_fields list.

My templates are quite generic so they are looping through the forms visible fields list and I would prefer not to alter these.

Answer (score 1):

Oke, my solution will be quite hacky, but you could maybe do something like this:

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):
        super(YourModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # You can also user insert, to add on a certain position
        self.visible_fields.append(self.instance.method())
```

Now a problem could be that you append a value, because I don't know how you render your fields. But you could fix this by append a `Field`-like object, which returns escaped (and saved) html on the necessary methods you call.

Other hacky option, add an additional field, set with an widget its attributes to `disabled=disabled`, and since a disabled `input` value isn't submitted with the form, set it `required=False`.